# Error log of launcher items

Tags: launcher

I created a launcher item by hand:

[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

Years ago output like this was in `.xsession-errors` but modern ubuntu seems to use a different file.

If this fails starting. Where can I see the output?

Answer (score 0):

I found the output of my failing launcher entry here:

```
.cache/upstart/gnome-session-Unity.log
```

Comment: @guntbert I updated the wording. Do you understand it now?